# can't display a value in the template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am having trouble displaying the value on the html template from the mysql database.

my view:

```
 from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required 
 from django.db.models import Count, Min, Sum, Avg, Max
 from .models import Gwtable
 import datetime

def index(request):
    max_value =  Gwtable.objects.all().aggregate(Max('salesprice'))
        return render(request, 'sql/index.html', context)
```

my html:

{{ max_value.values|floatformat:2 }}

Comment: Please show the rest of the view. And why do you think `.values` would work?

Comment: That's the whole view

Comment: No it isn't. You don't even render a template, or indeed return anything at all.

Comment: here is the missing section:     return render(request, 'sql/index.html', context)

Comment: You've still missing the line where you define `context`.

Comment: That was it. I never passed it appropriately in the context. Once I fixed that it came up in the template perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you fill the context object like that context= { 'max_values':max_values} your html tag is correct one.